# Creating an object with a function with arguments

Tags: javascript, function, object

Okay, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong because it appears correct to me and all my research online is proving me correct. But here is the code and instructions:

```
function newCar(make, model) {
    var car = {
      make = "Nissan",
      model = "model",
     };
}
```

The instructions are: Create a newCar function that takes in two parameters: make and model.
Using those parameters, create a car object, give it make and model properties, and return it from the function

Comment: You're neither using the parameters nor returning the object

Comment: Missing return statement error :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, minus bennygenel, for your relevant feedback! I figured it out.

Comment: Why don't you share the answer ?

Comment: Stack Overflow typically doesn't like homework questions. I don't entirely understand this. Maybe it's because students asking for homework help sometimes delete their questions. Per the [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*

Comment: That makes sense. This was early on when I was first learning so I like to think they've gotten a bit better since! Thanks @SJade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function newCar(make, model) {
  var car = {
  "make" : make,
  "model" : model,
  };

 return car;
}
```

Comment: `newCar("Nissan", "Altima");`

Answer (score 3):

You could either return just the object,

```js
function newCar(make, model) {
    return {
        make: make,
        model: model,
    };
}

console.log(newCar('BMW', '320ci'));
```

or use an instanciable function for using with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```js
function Car(make, model) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
}

console.log(new Car('BMW', '320ci'));
```